# roll-off of a digital zero-phase butterworth filter

Tags: scipy, signal-processing

Say I have a digital butterworth lowpass filter with an order of 3 and a cutoff of 4Hz at -3dB.  I understand that this filter should have a roll-off of 6*3 = 18dB/Octave.

If I now apply the filter a second time in the reverse direction (filtfilt in python scipy) in order to cancel the phase distortion, do I now have a filter with a roll-off 18*2 = 36dB/Octave?  Is the cutoff now -6dB at 4Hz?  Is there an easy way to find the cutoff at -3dB?  Do I still call it a 3rd order filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do I now have a filter with a roll-off 18*2 = 36dB/Octave?`

I believe so, but why not check and see?

`Is the cutoff now -6dB at 4Hz?`

Yes, but again, easy to confirm.

`Is there an easy way to find the cutoff at -3dB?`

Depends on what you consider easy. You need to find the the 1.5dB cutoff of the original filter, or measure.

`Do I still call it a 3rd order filter?`

It defies my intuition to talk about the order of this filter, but [according to these docs for the equivalent matlab function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html), it would be a 6th order filter.

Comment: Thank you.  If I were to check this, would the best way be to simply generate a chirp, filter it and then estimate the power spectrum?

Comment: That would work. You could also automate measurements of sine waves. It's easier to just look at signal peaks, which should work so long as you ignore edge effects.